# Compact class with a virtual function

Tags: c++, c++11

I have been asked in a discussion what are disadavntages of adding virtual function in a C++ class. I said that one disadvantage is that an object of the class has a pointer to its virtual table and for a small C++ class it add 8 bytes to its size on 64-bit platform. If one creates millions of instances of such class that increase memory consumption of a program.

OK, but why actually in C++ there is no such a thing as a tiny pointer to a virtual table or small pointer to a virtual table or compact pointer to a virtual table. Some thing like this:

```
class [[compact]] base {
  ~base(){}
  virtual f() = 0;
};

class [[tiny]] another_base {
  ~base(){}
  virtual g() = 0;
};

class [[small]] yet_another_base {
  ~base(){}
  virtual h() = 0;
};

class child : public base {
  virtual f();
};

class user_type : public another_base {
  ~base(){}
  virtual g();
};
```

Imagine that I am going to create lots of instances of `user_type` (in fact I once had this situation with a real program). By default a compiler creates an instance of `user_type` with size of 8 (on 64-bit). But with [[tiny]] attribute only it might be only 1 byte and with [[compact]] only 4 bytes.

Is this feature already available or not? If not it seems to me it is possible to implement it. Like having in a program hidden `tiny_vptr` and `compact_vptr` and just add first byte or first four bytes to them when it is necessary to find a real pointer to vtable. So in a program it is allowed to have only 256 [[tiny classes]] for example or 65000 [[small]] classses. It is like a choice betweeen maximum speed and saving some memory.

Comment: If it were implemented, it would only save memory if the derived class's first member was 1-byte aligned (otherwise there would be padding bytes between the vtable pointer and the first member). I suppose you could force the derived classes to be tightly packed so there would be no padding bytes, but then you're just getting into weird domain-specific territory.

Comment: The real harm of virtual functions is not because of the vptr, but because of their un-inlinability.

Comment: @SergeyA: OP is asking about saving memory. Un-inlineability doesn't really affect that.

Comment: @Cornstalks, not arguing that. However, OP is wrong on the actual essence and is trying to solve non-existing problem, while the main problem remains unsolved.

Comment: @Cornstalks, Agree. But [[compact]] with 4-byte ptr would be OK even if a derived class has a first member like int.

Comment: This question is essentially "why didn't the standards committee include this hardly useful feature that would really complicate the implementation". Not really 'on-topic'.

Comment: The pointer needs to point to a location in memory.  Since that location could be anywhere in memory the pointer needs to be able to hold any location the system could have.  There is a price to pay for polymorphism and part of that price is the size of a pointer being added to all of your classes.

Comment: There would also be a penalty in performance; the pointer points to the function that handles the operation, but if you reduced it to an index in a size-limited v-table, it would have to look up that v-table entry every time, based on the index, rather than just call the pointer.  In addition, every virtual function would require the same, which would really hurt memory spatial locality.  As it is now, a class will load entirely in cache, but change to v-table index lookups, and you'll have a much higher percentage of cache misses, with very little to show for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such feature.

Now, the vtable feature of C++ (at least the parts you use) can be emulated in either C or C++ with only a bit of syntactic sugar.

```
struct my_vtable {
  void(*dtor)(void*) = 0;
  void(*print)(void*) = 0;
  void(*add)(void*, int) = 0;
};

struct my_interface {
  my_vtable const* vtable = 0;
  ~my_interface() { vtable->dtor(this); }
  void print() { vtable->print(this); }
  void add(int x) { vtable->add(this, x); }
};
```

etc.  This requires a bit more work to get constructor and destructor cascades working, and virtual inheritance is a bit of a boor, and building a composite vtable from multiple inheritance is also work (especially if you want it clean).

But you have the tools.

Using such tools, you can implement your `[[tiny]]` vtable feature.

Now, if you care about this, a better approach is probably using proxy objects where you look up the table using an arbitrary function on arbitrary state you store in your instances.  You store the state in the instances, and the table elsewhere.

C++'s object system is *not* all that flexible.  It implements one way of arranging inheritance and OO.  There are many others that are useful, from layout changes through to functionality changes (for example, C++ does not support building one-off vtables for class instances, or otherwise dynamically creating new types).

Treat the C++ inheritance system as just one of many ways to write your OO code.  Know that you should have a good reason to step away from it, and make the resulting code as clean as you can, but don't be too afraid of not using C++ inheritance just because you have an inheritance relationship.